# Where did the class name 'hero' come from in CSS?

Tags: css, class, naming-conventions

A widely adopted CSS naming practice is to use `hero` as the class name applied to a site's main banner.

Where did this naming convention come from, and is it a reference to something in particular?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

'Hero' is a word beloved by marketing people that describes the main focal point of an advertisement etc.

[https://unbounce.com/conversion-glossary/definition/hero-shot/#:~:text=Definition,benefits%20and%20context%20of%20use](https://unbounce.com/conversion-glossary/definition/hero-shot/#:%7E:text=Definition,benefits%20and%20context%20of%20use).

Comment: link gone unfortunately :(